# Prikry sequence is countable

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I am reading the chapter on Prikry forcing of *Handbook of Set Theory*. On page 1353:

> **1.4 Lemma** Let $G\subseteq \mathcal P$ be generic for $\langle \mathcal P, \le \rangle$. Then $\bigcup\{p\mid \exists(\langle p, A\rangle \in G)\}$ is an $\omega$-sequence cofinal in $\kappa$.

The proof below perfectly explains why $G$ is cofinal: Let $$D_\alpha=\{\langle p, A\rangle\in \mathcal P \mid \langle p, A\rangle > \langle q, B\rangle\text{ and } \max(p)>\alpha\}\text.$$
Then $D_\alpha$ is dense, so $G\cap D_\alpha\ne\varnothing$ implies $G$ contains $\langle p, A\rangle$ where $\max(p)$ is very large.

However, that $G$ is countable doesn't look particularly clear to me.

Comment: It's an increasing union of finite sets. What else could it be?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Each $p$ is finite, but is $G$ finite? What do you mean by "increasing union"?

Comment: Compatible conditions must have linearly ordered stems. Namely, one stem must extend the other (or they are equal, of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Lemma.** Suppose that $(p,A)$ and $(q,B)$ are compatible conditions, then $p$ is an initial segment of $q$ or vice versa.

*Proof.* Let $(r,C)$ be a common extension. Then $r$ is an end-extension of both $q$ and $p$. Therefore the conclusion must hold. $\square$

> **Corollary.** If $G$ is a $V$-generic filter, then $\{p\mid\exists A,(p,A)\in G\}$ is a chain of subsets.

*Proof.* Think. $\square$

> **Corollary.** If $s$ is a Prikry sequence, then $s$ is of order type $\omega$.

*Proof.* As $s$ is the union of a chain of finite sets. Since clearly $s$ is not finite, it must have order type $\omega$. $\square$